# Locking in multi-threaded pywinauto send keys

Tags: python, pywinauto, concurrent.futures

I'm new to `pywinauto` and I'm creating several notepad windows and typing a text in all of them. However, this is not dependent on each other, so this can be run concurrently using threads.

However, when I try to do the same, the text get messed up because there are several threads trying to access the `type_keys()` method at the same time. Is there any way I can achieve the same concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

There is another method `.set_text("...")` that doesn't require window to be in focus. It's available for edit box only.

`.type_keys()` or `.click_input()` is not a good choice for concurrent automation or for a locked machine / minimized RDP. More details can be found in [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. `set_text` does seem like a good choice but I'm not sure if I can use them like `app.dialog.set_text(...)`. Is there any alternative way of doing the same?

Comment: For backend=“win32”, there is method .send_keystrokes() that can make some key combinations working. All is mentioned in the Remote Execution Guide.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this  importing keybord from pywinauto and  the send the line you would like to send  this is a small exemple  :

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import keyboard 
app = application.Application()
app.start("Notepad.exe")
keyboard.SendKeys('hello')
```

with this code you will open Notepade and write hello in Notepad , I just created to .py file and both have same code and I did call them on main file and worked perfect
I created A.py and put code on it  and I created B.py and put same code and in C.py I did import A , import B it and run it it did open 2 Notpad and wrote the text   look for this example :
A.py

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import keyboard 
app = application.Application()
app.start("Notepad.exe")
keyboard.SendKeys('hello')
```

B.py

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import keyboard 
app = application.Application()
app.start("Notepad.exe")
keyboard.SendKeys('hello friends',with_spaces=True)
```

C.py

```
import A,B
```

and run C.py make sur all the files are saved in same folder

Comment: Thank you for this. But I would like them to be on the same python file, using threads. This addresses the issue but doesn't seem feasible enough. I tried using the custom `keyboard` from the `pywinauto` using threads, but I hit the same issue as I described in my problem.

Comment: Hi @AndrewScott I am sorry my solution did not help you I just tried and but all the code in same file but without using threads it worked , but for threads I am not sur , I will look for more details or try to find best solution for you